# SSL certificates and whether a wildcard common name will support domain.com

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate

I purchased an inexpensive SSL Cert from GoDaddy. Right now everything on production is hosted off of `www.domain.com`. When specifying the common name would a wildcard (i.e. `*.domain.com`) cover the case of a lack of a third-level domain such as domain.com? Just to be sure, I made it for `www.domain.com` rather than a wildcard. If it matters, I will be using with nginx and a mod_passenger.

If I want to cover everything including `domain.com` and `staging.domain.com`, `www.domain.com` etc., would a wildcard be the proper cert? Does the inexpensive GoDaddy cert ($12.99 / year) cover wildcard certs (it didn't seem to for me)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be getting a wildcard SSL certificate from *anyone* for $12.99. They are typically much more expensive; I see on GoDaddy's site that their base price for wildcard SSL is $199/year, for instance.

A "normal" SSL certificate like you purchased should already serve both www.example.com and example.com.

You can probably get away with self-signed certificates for your development/staging servers.

Comment: thx, cool - that's what I figured regarding price. would a self-signed certificate (*.domain.com) be able to handle domain.com? Or do you just send everything to www.domain.com?

Comment: A "normal" SSL certificate like you purchased should already serve both www.example.com and example.com.

Comment: thx for info MH

Comment: @timpone: *Technically* the answer is no. `*.domain.com` does not match `domain.com` but I think most registrars will automatically add `domain.com` to your cert as an alternative name (SAN, also known as a UCC certificate) so modern browsers will see the cert as valid.

Comment: Could someone with edit permission incorporate @DerfK's remark in the answer? I almost overlooked it.